# Error on sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386

Tags: linux, kali-linux

When I type

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: python-gi (< 3.7.2) but 3.2.2-2 is to be installed
libxfixes3 : Breaks: xserver-xorg-core (< 2:1.14)
libxi6 : Breaks: xserver-xorg-core (< 2:1.14)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held      packages.
```

I'm using Kali Linux whatever  the newest version is because I got it last week.

Comment: Is this a new install or a distribution upgrade? I ask, because I had similar problems on Ubuntu (also Debian-derived) when I upgraded, because of additional repositories that I had added during the previous installation. Check that you have none of these.

Comment: Fresh install as of a week ago. But between now and then there were software updates.

Comment: I wonder if `sudo apt-get install -f` will fix this (maybe not). Isn't libssl0.9.8 an old version?

Comment: IDK if its an old version, is there a newer one? would the full command be `sudo apt-get install -f libssl0.9.8:i386`?

Comment: So I ran this command: `sudo  apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
` And now I get this error when I try to install: `E: Package 'libssl0.9.8:i386' has no installation candidate`

Comment: `apt-get install -f` tries to fix any problems like broken dependency.

Comment: It took a while to do. I'm not at my Kali computer right now, but when I am, I'll try to install it.

Comment: For what it's worth, my (latest) Ubuntu 14.10 uses `libssl1.0.0`, though 0.9.8 is still available, but with conflicts. 1.0.0 ought to be available for Kali and should install without conflicts.

Comment: Let me try, I'll get back in the morning.

Comment: Ha! I already had it! It wasn't letting me install 0.9.8 because it was outdated! Although, I still get the error when installing, so I will do a fresh install.

Comment: fresh install fixed it

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? (You're allowed to answer your own question.)  Comments are transient, plus a resolution buried in a long comment thread isn't obvious.  That will help others looking for an answer who spot your question.  Thanks.